# How can db-sync "match" a data_hash to specific outputs?

Tags: cardano-db-sync

Looking at the [db-sync schema](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/doc/schema.md#tx_out), I see the `tx_out` table has a `data_hash` column, but I can't make sense of why this column is not on the `tx` table instead. From the [Alonzo CDDL](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/blob/37322df14d44d1370e8a72b677815d64a92baa00/alonzo/test/cddl-files/alonzo.cddl), I can see the scripts are part of the `transaction_witness_sets`, which is part of the block, so I don't see how one could match a script data from a witness to an output in a transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to CDDL, the transaction output itself has a `data_hash`: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/blob/37322df14d44d1370e8a72b677815d64a92baa00/alonzo/test/cddl-files/alonzo.cddl#L73

PS: I can't believe I missed that...